# Multiple Entry visa for parents visiting me in UK

Tags: uk, netherlands, multiple-entry, standard-visitor-visas, south-african-citizens

I am a South African citizen currently living in the UK with a Tier 2 visa. My parents have recently moved to the Netherlands. If they want to visit us, they would need a visa. For this, I have a couple questions:

1. They are probably going to visit us a lot. What would they need to do in order to qualify for a multiple entry visa?
2. My wife is currently pregnant and my parent's first visit to us will be very short notice when the baby is born; how should they apply for the visa, since we do not have exact dates, and they can not book tickets yet?

Should I give them some kind of letter or something for when they apply for the visa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They are probably going to visit us a lot. What would they need to do
>   in order to qualify for a multiple entry visa?

The 'Standard Visitor Visa' is multiple-entry by default so there is nothing special they need to do.

> ...how should they apply for the visa, since we do not have exact
>   dates, and they can not book tickets yet?

Unlike other countries, the UK prefers that applicants do not purchase tickets or make bookings in advance of a decision. This is explicitly addressed in the guidance...

[image]

> Should I give them some kind of letter or something for when they
>   apply for the visa?

It's optional based upon what you wrote, but it's a good idea to include something that shows your status in the UK (like a scan of your T2 and a scan of your passport's portrait page). I am assuming that you are not financing their visit.

Comment: Thanks, They will be paying for the visit. Seeing as the Standard Visitor Visa is multiple entry, i guess they will need to apply for a long term one then. Then we should be all sorted ?

Comment: Applying for a long-term one would not be advisable because it wastes money. Read http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60848/uk-visitor-visa-max-validity-period-policy/60856#60856

Comment: Thanks, good to know. What an easy way to make money for them. We are only looking for 1 year or something like that.

Comment: "Unlike other countries, the UK prefers that applicants do not purchase tickets or make bookings in advance of a decision" sounds as if the UK is the only country with this policy. Suggest "other countries" be changed to read "some countries" or "some other countries".